# How to make the prints of a function appear to a shiny app user

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the `psoptim()` from the pso R package. The function genertes a print for each iteration of the algorithm, and I want that output to be visible to a shiny app user

This is an example that shows the prints of the algorithm:

```
library(pso)
psoptim(rep(NA,2),function(x) 20+sum(x^2-10*cos(2*pi*x)),lower=-5,upper=5,control=list("fnscale" = -1, "trace" = 1, "maxit" = 60, "REPORT" = 1))
```

This is what I've tried so far, without any success:

```
library(shiny)
library(pso)

withConsoleRedirect <- function(containerId, expr) {
  # Change type="output" to type="message" to catch stderr
  # (messages, warnings, and errors) instead of stdout.
  txt <- capture.output(results <- expr, type = "output")
  if (length(txt) > 0) {
    insertUI(paste0("#", containerId), where = "beforeEnd",
             ui = paste0(txt, "\n", collapse = "")
    )
  }
  results
}

# Example usage

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run_optim", "Run"),
  pre(id = "console")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent("run_optim",{
    #invalidateLater(1000)
    
    withConsoleRedirect("console", {
      psoptim(rep(NA,2),function(x) 20+sum(x^2-10*cos(2*pi*x)),lower=-5,upper=5,control=list("fnscale" = -1, "trace" = 1, "maxit" = 60, "REPORT" = 1))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: `pso::psoptim` is using `message(..)` (based on https://github.com/cran/pso/blob/master/R/psoptim.R#L83), so we need to tell `capture.output` to capture the messages instead of the print/cat outputs.

Please try this variant:

```r
doSomething <- function(...) message("hello world: ", sample(100, 1), "\n")
withConsoleRedirect <- function(textAreaId, expr, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
  txt <- capture.output(res <- expr, type = "message")
  if (length(txt) && any(nzchar(txt))) {
    oldtxt <- session$input[[textAreaId]]
    if (!nzchar(oldtxt[1])) oldtxt <- oldtxt[-1]
    updateTextAreaInput(session, textAreaId,
                        value = paste(trimws(c(oldtxt, txt)), collapse = "\n"))
  }
  res
}
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("btn", "Run"),
  shinyjs::disabled(textAreaInput("console", "Console", rows = 5)),
  actionButton("clr", "Clear text area")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    withConsoleRedirect("console", {
      doSomething()
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$clr, {
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "console", value = "")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

In this example, I suggest using a `textarea` html input element to show the text. Since I don't intend in this case for the user to be able to add anything to it, I use the `shinyjs` package to disable it (not allow user entry), though this is not required by your requested mechanism.

Since this is one element that is always appended-to, I offer the ability to clear the text area.

It's not hard to see prepending a timestamp to each message if this could be a long-running operation (though in that case you might choose to use `future` or some other backgrounding capability so that your shiny app does not freeze).

Comment: The thing with your solution is that it displays the functions' final output, rather than displaying the prints that it usually shows in the console. Note that you have to click te button every time to get an extra print

It should display the prints synchronously during the computing process

Comment: If something is `print`ed or `cat`ed on function execution, then it captures it. If you need it to capture it in real time, then you need a _completely different_ implementation that involves another R process, its output going to a file, and a frequent `invalidate` loop that looks for more output. So I fail to see what is different from the output printed by `psoptim` and that by my `doSomething`, is my function printing in a different way? Is it something that `utils::capture.output` is failing to capture? (Perhaps it should be `type="message"` for you?

Comment: psoptim() might be printing in a different way... The font color of the prints is red, so it might be "printing" the outputs with a different function to print(). Try running the 2 line example I gave in the beginning, there you can see the prints (in a red font)...

Redefine doSomething with:

doSomething <- function(){psoptim(rep(NA,2),function(x) 20+sum(x^2-10*cos(2*pi*x)),lower=-5,upper=5,control=list("fnscale" = -1, "trace" = 1, "maxit" = 60, "REPORT" = 1))}

And you'll see the problem

Comment: After I looked at the function you are using (https://github.com/cran/pso/blob/master/R/psoptim.R#L83), it is using `message`, so your first function can never work. Change to `type="message"`, and read up on `?capture.output` and `?sink` to understand that you must capture one or the other, and they are different.

Comment: See my (barely) updated answer to see if it works for you.